# Dynamic checkboxes react get values

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm making an API call to retrieve an array of values using Axios which I'm then displaying with corresponding inputs/labels in the below code:

```
checkList = this.state.assignment.specs.map(function(spec, index) {
   return(<div><input type="checkbox" id="assignment" style={{color: '#5d8f90'}} />&nbsp;&nbsp;<label style={{display: 'inline'}}>{spec}</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;</div> );
});
```

When a user invokes a button, I want to be able to get a list of the elements if they were checked/unchecked, ideally something like the below:

```
["checked", "unchecked", "checked"]
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself, there's a library called `react-checkbox-group` that solves my needs here.

https://github.com/ziad-saab/react-checkbox-group

Comment: I think it is all about set values and not get values

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to add `onclick()` listeners to the buttons. These listeners simply call `setState()`. Then when you need the values, you get it from `this.state` rather than from the controls themselves.

Comment: Any chance you have an example? thank you very much!

Comment: @Viper Not immediately available. I suggest you try some googling to find something that fits your needs.